# Change values in pandas dataframe according to value_counts()

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have following pandas dataframe :

```
import pandas as pd 
from pandas import Series, DataFrame

data = DataFrame({'Qu1': ['apple', 'potato', 'cheese', 'banana', 'cheese', 'banana', 'cheese', 'potato', 'egg'],
              'Qu2': ['sausage', 'banana', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'sausage', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana'],
              'Qu3': ['apple', 'potato', 'sausage', 'cheese', 'cheese', 'potato', 'cheese', 'potato', 'egg']})
```

I'd like to change values in columns `Qu1`,`Qu2`,`Qu3` according to `value_counts()` when value count great or equal some number

For example for `Qu1` column

```
>>> pd.value_counts(data.Qu1) >= 2
cheese     True
potato     True
banana     True
apple     False
egg       False
```

I'd like to keep values `cheese`,`potato`,`banana`, because each value has at least two appearances.

From values `apple` and `egg` I'd like to create value`others`

For column `Qu2` no changes :

```
>>> pd.value_counts(data.Qu2) >= 2
banana     True
apple      True
sausage    True
```

The final result as in attached `test_data`

```
test_data = DataFrame({'Qu1': ['other', 'potato', 'cheese', 'banana', 'cheese', 'banana', 'cheese', 'potato', 'other'],
                  'Qu2': ['sausage', 'banana', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'sausage', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana'],
                  'Qu3': ['other', 'potato', 'other', 'cheese', 'cheese', 'potato', 'cheese', 'potato', 'other']})
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would create a dataframe of same shape where the corresponding entry is the value count:

```
data.apply(lambda x: x.map(x.value_counts()))
Out[229]: 
   Qu1  Qu2  Qu3
0    1    2    1
1    2    4    3
2    3    3    1
3    2    3    3
4    3    3    3
5    2    2    3
6    3    4    3
7    2    4    3
8    1    4    1
```

And, use the results in [`df.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) to return "other" where the corresponding entry is smaller than 2:

```
data.where(data.apply(lambda x: x.map(x.value_counts()))>=2, "other")

      Qu1      Qu2     Qu3
0   other  sausage   other
1  potato   banana  potato
2  cheese    apple   other
3  banana    apple  cheese
4  cheese    apple  cheese
5  banana  sausage  potato
6  cheese   banana  cheese
7  potato   banana  potato
8   other   banana   other
```

Comment: Quite a bit more elegant & faster than my approach with `.replace()`!

Comment: @StefanJansen Thanks. :) In my experience, `.replace()` is generally slower than `.map()` so I tend to use map when both are possible. Though I still think the apply-map-value_counts combination may be repeating things but I couldn't find a better alternative.

Comment: Thanks ! Elegant solution. How the `.where() with >=2` works ?

Comment: `df.where()` takes a condition. When this condition holds, returns values from the original dataframe; otherwise it returns from another dataframe or a constant. For example `df.where(df>5, df2)` would return a dataframe where the values are from df if they are greater than 5, or from df2 if the values are smaller than or equal to 5. It is equivalent to `df[df<=5] = df2`.

Comment: I added `inplace ="True"` and got `TypeError: Cannot do inplace boolean setting on mixed-types with a non np.nan value`

Comment: You can try assigning directly: `data = data.where(data.apply(lambda x: x.map(x.value_counts()))>=2, "other")`

Comment: I'd like to execute `where` on several columns only , and exclude others . What a best way to do it ?

Comment: It looks like your issue has been resolved with @EdChum's answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/37318069/2285236

Answer (score 2):

You could:

```
value_counts = df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts())

         Qu1  Qu2  Qu3
apple    1.0  3.0  1.0
banana   2.0  4.0  NaN
cheese   3.0  NaN  3.0
egg      1.0  NaN  1.0
potato   2.0  NaN  3.0
sausage  NaN  2.0  1.0
```

Then build a `dictionary` that will contain the replacements for each column:

```
import cycle
replacements = {}
for col, s in value_counts.items():
    if s[s<2].any():
        replacements[col] = dict(zip(s[s < 2].index.tolist(), cycle(['other'])))

replacements
{'Qu1': {'egg': 'other', 'apple': 'other'}, 'Qu3': {'egg': 'other', 'apple': 'other', 'sausage': 'other'}}
```

Use the `dictionary` to replace the values:

```
df.replace(replacements)

      Qu1      Qu2     Qu3
0   other  sausage   other
1  potato   banana  potato
2  cheese    apple   other
3  banana    apple  cheese
4  cheese    apple  cheese
5  banana  sausage  potato
6  cheese   banana  cheese
7  potato   banana  potato
8   other   banana   other
```

or wrap the loop in a `dictionary` comprehension:

```
from itertools import cycle

df.replace({col: dict(zip(s[s < 2].index.tolist(), cycle(['other']))) for col, s in value_counts.items() if s[s < 2].any()})
```

However, this is not only more cumbersome but also slower than using `.where`. Testing with 3,000 columns:

```
df = pd.concat([df for i in range(1000)], axis=1)

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 9 entries, 0 to 8
Columns: 3000 entries, Qu1 to Qu3
dtypes: object(3000)
```

Using `.replace()`:

```
%%timeit
value_counts = df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts())
df.replace({col: dict(zip(s[s < 2].index.tolist(), cycle(['other']))) for col, s in value_counts.items() if s[s < 2].any()})

1 loop, best of 3: 4.97 s per loop
```

vs `.where()`:

```
%%timeit
df.where(df.apply(lambda x: x.map(x.value_counts()))>=2, "other")

1 loop, best of 3: 2.01 s per loop
```