# Exclude columns from pandas where()

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have following pandas df :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np    

pd_df = pd.DataFrame({'Qu1': ['apple', 'potato', 'cheese', 'banana', 'cheese', 'banana', 'cheese', 'potato', 'egg'],
              'Qu2': ['sausage', 'banana', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', np.nan, 'banana', 'banana', 'banana'],
              'Qu3': ['apple', 'potato', 'sausage', 'cheese', 'cheese', 'potato', 'cheese', 'potato', 'egg']})
```

I'd like to implement `where()` on two columns only `Qu1` and `Qu2` and keep the rest 
[original stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37239627/change-values-in-pandas-dataframe-according-to-value-counts)
, so I created `pd1`

```
pd1 = pd_df.where(pd_df.apply(lambda x: x.map(x.value_counts()))>=2,
                              "other")[['Qu1', 'Qu2']]
```

Then I added a rest of `pd_df`,`pd_df['Qu3']` to `pd1`

```
pd1['Qu3'] = pd_df['Qu3']
pd_df = []
```

**My question is** : Originally I want to execute `where()` on part of `df` and keep rest of columns as is, so could the code above be dangerous for large dataset ? Can I harm the original data this way ? If yes what the best way to do it ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just explicitly take a `copy` of the orig df and then overwrite on a selection of that df:

```
In [40]:
pd1 = pd_df.copy()
pd1[['Qu1', 'Qu2']] = pd1[['Qu1', 'Qu2']].where(pd_df.apply(lambda x: x.map(x.value_counts()))>=2,
                              "other")
pd1

Out[40]:
      Qu1     Qu2      Qu3
0   other   other    apple
1  potato  banana   potato
2  cheese   apple  sausage
3  banana   apple   cheese
4  cheese   apple   cheese
5  banana   other   potato
6  cheese  banana   cheese
7  potato  banana   potato
8   other  banana      egg
```

So the difference here is that we only operate on a section of the df, rather than the whole df and then select the cols of interest

**update**

If you want to just overwrite those cols then just select those:

```
In [48]:
pd_df[['Qu1', 'Qu2']] = pd_df[['Qu1', 'Qu2']].where(pd_df.apply(lambda x: x.map(x.value_counts()))>=2,
                              "other")
pd_df

Out[48]:
      Qu1     Qu2      Qu3
0   other   other    apple
1  potato  banana   potato
2  cheese   apple  sausage
3  banana   apple   cheese
4  cheese   apple   cheese
5  banana   other   potato
6  cheese  banana   cheese
7  potato  banana   potato
8   other  banana      egg
```

Comment: Thanks ! My data set is approximately 30G , would `copy` produce another 30G data set in memory ?

Comment: Your question showed you creating a copy of the 2 cols, if you just want to overwrite those columns in the original then you can just remove the `copy` line and do the second line on the original df